# Cassandra Binary Protocol Scalability

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql3, cassandra-cli

I have been working with Cassandra(v1.2,v2.0,v2.1) for quite some time.
Earlier i was able to see the Cassandra's Write scalability (v1.2,v2.1) with Thrift protocol with 5 nodes. I am trying to evaluate the Write scalability aspects of Cassandra(2.1) Binary Protocol with batching.

We see that Cassandra New protocol has better performance than Thrift.
Surprisingly i see that Cassandra is not scaling well with binary protocol with batching. We have experimented enough number of times the following :

a) Various batch sizes like : 100,1000,..10000

b) Off_heap Memtable stuff

c) Varied Number of Clients ( We are using YCSB Client)

d) WriteTimeout to 5sec and 10 sec

For eg. 
The write throughput obtained for 3 Nodes, 5 Nodes and 10 Nodes has not much difference.

Schema { UUID,DateComponentOfTimestamp, Timestamp, float value} 
First two columns form a key.

I have tried it on physical cluster setup and AWS EC2 instances too.
I see a lot of experiments were done with Single node setup Binary protocol.

Are there any known benchmarks (internal or external) for Scalability of Binary Protocol with and without batching ?

Did i miss anything and can anyone guide me in this regard ?

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Are your batches writing to multiple partitions (in your case, inserts with different UUIDs among the batch)?  That could explain why you are not seeing much performance improvement when adding nodes since writes would likely have to touch all nodes, putting a lot of work on the coordinator.   Could you share your code by chance?  YCSB's cassandra code uses thrift, was curious if you wrote your own client or using some of the CQL implementations out there (i.e.: https://github.com/jbellis/YCSB/blob/master/cassandra/src/main/java/com/yahoo/ycsb/db/CassandraCQLClient.java)

Comment: Good article with regards to batching with the native protocol that's worth a read: https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword-40f00e35e23e

Comment: We are using CQL implementations provided by the link you mentioned. We see data distribution is uniform and we are using Murmer3 partitioner. I didn't get your point regarding writing to multiple partitions. We are using executeAsync() with batchstatement and leaving it to cassandra as done by YCSB client. Also we have tried the LOGGED and UNLOGGED batch statements. Did i miss anything ?

Comment: I see, we must not be referring to the same nomenclature for 'batch' then.  The link I provided does inserts/updates of many columns within the same key.  This is effectively considered 1 insert operation.  In CQL there is the concept of a 'BatchStatement' where multiple statements are processed as one batch, of these could be going to multiple partitions which requires reaching out to a number of nodes (which can degrade performance).

Comment: Hrmm, I must have missed the last part of your comment where you reference BatchStatement, so maybe we are referring to the same thing.  You must not be using the code I referenced, since that doesn't use executeAsync() or BatchStatement.  Can you share your YCSB client as a gist or something so I can take a look?

Comment: Yes Andy, we are actually having multiple statements with different partition keys within same batch and you may be right regarding performance degrade. We are going to evaluate this with correction now (having same partition key statements in a single batch) and will let you know if this solved the issue. Thereafter I will share the jist of the YCSB code.